# PHP: Replace line in a file or add if not found

Tags: php, file, replace, addition

I have a file (messages.txt) that looks something like this:

```
112233|A line of text here.
aabbcc|More text here.
223344|And the list goes on...
```

and code like this that works as expected:

```
    $filename = 'messages.txt';
    $data = file($filename);
    file_put_contents($filename, implode('', 
      array_map(function($data) {
        return stristr($data,'aabbcc') ? "aabbcc|This would be a NEW line.\n" : $data;
      }, file($filename))
    ));
```

So this will replace the line where it finds aabbcc with a new one.
How do I edit this so that if the line isn't found, it would add it at the end of the txt file? Is there an easy way to do this or would I need to alter the code quite a bit to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: use `file_get_contents` and `strpos` to find if the line already exists. If it returns FALSE then you can use an `if` statement to append.

Comment: Your current code will have issues with something like `556677|Sample of aabbcc to mess with you`

Comment: Looks like a database would be more worthwile than adapting this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I thought of using a database, but this is for a really simple use and the file would be holding a max 30 lines or so. Each line starts with a string that's different for different users (actually YouTube channel ID's) and the text after | will never contain this ID. Marked this thread as solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$message_exists = false;

$filename = 'messages.txt';
$data = file($filename);
file_put_contents($filename, implode('', 
  array_map(function($data) use (&$message_exists){
    $result = substr($data, 0, strlen('aabbcc|')) === 'aabbcc|';
    if($result)
    {
        $message_exists = true;
    }
    return $result ? "aabbcc|This would be a NEW line.\n" : $data;
  }, file($filename))
));

if(!$message_exists)
{
    file_put_contents($filename, "aabbcc|This would be a NEW line.\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!